# FullCanlendar upgrade v3 to v6

Tags: salesforce, fullcalendar, visualforce

I am new to FullCalendar. Our application already using FullCalendar v3 in salesforce. I have seen documentation looks like V6 version is having diiferent method than the v3. like getView() method method not exists.

Can any guide me how to implement v6?

Thank you,
Sonal G

```
var view = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView');
```

Getting error as this method not found.

One more error coming while loading event dynamically

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined

moment is not defined

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc shows you the methods and options available in the latest version. And read the getting started guide there, too. Think of it more like a replacement than an upgrade...you'll need to change quite a lot of your code. P.s. if you want to continue using moment, that is independent of fullcalendar and nothing prevents you from including it if you want to

Comment: Could you please advice me that can we upgrade or not?

Comment: Yes of course you can. It takes a small effort but it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat. Given that the [v6 release notes](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v5) state

> Beyond installing some new packages and rewriting some import statements, there are very few breaking API changes.

I looked at the docs for v5, and [their migration section](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/upgrading-from-v4#upgrading-from-v3) says

> Many developers will be upgrading from v3 instead of v4. We will likely release a separate guide for this process before the official v5 is released. In the meantime, here are some tips for upgrading from v3 -> v5 in lieu of a full guide:
>
> - Follow the [v3 -> v4 upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3) but ignore the following areas:
>   “Initialization” and anything related to  tags or stylesheets
>   anything related to content injection, such as options with the words render, text, or html in them
> - Learn how to install and initialize a v5 calendar from the Getting Started article.
> - Follow this v4 -> v5 upgrade guide afterwards.

So that's what I'm trying to do.